# Differences between optJSON and getJSON

Tags: android

```
String strJson="{
             \"Employee\" :[
             {
                \"id\":\"01\",
                \"name\":\"Gopal Varma\",
                \"salary\":\"500000\"
             },
             {
                \"id\":\"02\",
                \"name\":\"Sairamkrishna\",
                \"salary\":\"500000\"
             },
             {
                \"id\":\"03\",
                \"name\":\"Sathish kallakuri\",
                \"salary\":\"600000\"
             }
             ] 
          }";
    try {
        JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
        JSONArray jsonArray1=jsonObject.optJSONArray("Employee");
        JSONArray jsonArray2=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Employee");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In the above example what is the difference between optJSONArray("Employee") and getJSONArray("Employee") as both return the JSONArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that optString returns the empty string ("") if the key you specify doesn't exist. getString on the other hand throws a JSONException. Use getString if it's an error for the data to be missing, or optString if you're not sure if it will be there.

check this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150101212410/http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optString(java.lang.String)